# How to deploy app from bitbucket to azure

Tags: azure, bitbucket-pipelines

My pipe in bitbucket:

```
- pipe: microsoft/azure-cli-run:1.0.2
  variables:
    AZURE_APP_ID: $AZURE_APP_ID
    AZURE_PASSWORD: $AZURE_PASSWORD
    AZURE_TENANT_ID: $AZURE_TENANT_ID
```

Where is `AZURE_APP_ID`? On Azure -> App Services I can see a table with my apps but no application id. And what password is it? I haven't set a password anywhere. And `tenant id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to [create an Azure service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest) in your azure subscription to enable connecting bitbucket to azure services.
When you create the service principal you will get a set of information after successful creation from which you can extract the app ID and tenant ID. This is via azure CLI.

```
az ad sp list --show-mine --query '[].{"id":"appId", "tenant":"appOwnerTenantId"}'
```

This information along with your azure password is what you need to supply to the [bitbucket pipeline](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-microsoft-azure-900820699.html) to enable deployment from your repo to azure.